# What is a "Field" associated with a class and how does it differ from methods in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Both field and method take arguments in same way and have similar syntax for calling them. How does one differ from the other?

```
from tkinter import *

# Window() is a blueprint for making object in tkinter library.
main_window = Window()

# minsize() is shown as "Field" with yellow color and capital "f" in PyCharm.
window.minsize(width=400, height=100)

# mainloop() is a method and shown with magenta-Ish color and "m" in PyCharm.
main_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're only calling methods of the Window class here. There are no fields shown, only named parameters

Comment: I don't have pycharm installed, so just a guess. tkinter defines `def wm_minsize(...)` and then assigns that object to `minsize` as an attribute of the class. I think that's where pycharm decides its a "field". You could check `wm_minsize` to see what it says. And you could write a quick subclass to `Window` that assigns a class level variable `foo = mainloop` to see if the same thing happens. Or even do `Window.foo = Window.mainloop`.

Answer (score 0):

Fields and method parameters are not the same at all.

If they are named similarly, that's only a coincidence, not a requirement.

Here's an example of different ways Python allows you to use method parameters.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.field = None

    def method(self, parameter=None):
        self.field = parameter
        print(self.field)

f = Foo()
f.method()  # default parameter 
f.method(1)  # implied parameter
f.method(parameter=2)  # named parameter
```

Class *constructors* are methods can be used to initialize fields

Regarding Pycharm, a function-field could be defined as

```
def __init__(self):
    def __minsize(width, height):
        ... 
    self.minsize = __minsize
```

Whereas a method would be defined like `bar` above